# MariaDB, Workbench, and ON DELETE SET DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

I have a non-nullable foreign key that I need to be set to default on a delete of the other table. I'm using MariaDB, and exporting the SQL script from a model in MySQL Workbench.

MariaDB supports ON DELETE SET DEFAULT according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/constraint_type-foreign-key-constraint/
MySQL documentation says that while it's "allowed by the MySQL Server, it is rejected as invalid by InnoDB."

So I have two questions: can I be sure the default storage engine on MariaDB does support it (or does the documentation link above just imply that the server itself supports it), and, assuming it does, how do I get around the issue of Workbench not letting me set the damn option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the question is really *two* questions.

Does MariaDB support `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`. Yes. But, the more important question is really

**Does MariaDB have any storage engines that support `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`?**

---

I believe MariaDB will accept the syntax (at the server level). But when the server passes that down to the underlying storage engine, the storage engine is going to balk and reject it.

For example, this may be able to get this passed to tables using the MyISAM storage engine. (I'm not sure about that, we don't ever define foreign keys on MyISAM tables.) If it does get passed to MyISAM, it would be a stretch to say "it works", because nothing "foreign key" actually works with MyISAM. MyISAM effectively ignores foreign key constraints.

I think there's a note in the documentation you referenced that MariaDB had a storage engine named **PBXT** that would accept this. But development of PBXT has stopped, and it's disabled in MariaDB 5.5. To get the storage engine enabled, you'd have to do a build of MariaDB with that enabled. But that's a whole rigmarole, just to say "MariaDB supports `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`".

The InnoDB storage engine doesn't support it. And XtraDB is an improved InnoDB, but I don't think this is an area that they improved. (It's worth a quick test, if you're using XtraDB.)

If you're using the InnoDB storage engine for your table, then the answer is that MariaDB doesn't support `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`.

If you're using some other storage engine, it might. But I think the only storage engine in MariaDB that supported it was PBXT.

---

Reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/foreign-keys/

> The allowed actions for ON DELETE and ON UPDATE are:
>
> SET DEFAULT: Only worked with PBXT. Similar to SET NULL, but the foreign key columns were set to their default values. If default values do not exist, an error is produced.

---

The workaround, of course, is to not rely on the FOREIGN KEY constraint rule to do that for you. Just set the rule to ON DELETE RESTRICT.

And before you delete rows from the parent table, you can perform an update on referencing rows in the child table, and you can set the foreign key column on those rows to any valid value you want. Then, you can delete the rows from the parent.